# Day and Night Display Mode

Tags: 2013

i would like to add a functionality that allows a user to toogle between day and night display mode.

Do you know if SharePoint 2013 offers this kind of mechanism in a standard way ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If you ask is there out of the box solution to toggle between day and night display mode than answer is No.

But, you can always go for customization and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new feature in SharePoint 2013 called as Themes. What you can do is you can create your own custom themes for Day and Night. Please check the below link for reference on how to create Themes in SharePoint 2013 and how you can apply it.
[Check out this blog.](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/create-sharepoint2013-theme-using-color-palette-tool)

Comment: Changing the theme will affect all the users, no ? In my case, the users use the portal in different time zone. For some users it is the day while for the others is the night. What i need, it's the ability for one user to change the display.

Comment: I guess you are allowed to do some custom developments on JQuery and JavaScript. Do one the create your separate CSS and create a button on master page. On the click on the button your call your JavaScript. which will take the time of your browser using its locale, the time zone is sorted and the apply your CSS based of time. Let me know if you have any more doubts.